# CoffeeScript instance methods

Tags: coffeescript, instance-methods

I have a CoffeeScipt class defined like such

```
class Foo
  a: 1
  b: 2
  main: ->
   if a == 1
    log(1)

  log: (num) ->
    console.log(num)
f = new Foo
f.main()
```

it keeps erroring out saying that log is not defined. I tried making it `@log:` didn't work either. I tried making the `->` of main a `=>` and did not work either. How can I call instance methods from within the class itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `@` when calling instance methods and fields not when defining:

```
class Foo
  a: 1
  b: 2

  main: ->
   if @a == 1
    @log(1)

  log: (num) ->
    console.log(num)

f = new Foo()
f.main()
```

Defining methods with `@` like this

```
@log: (num) ->
    console.log(num)
```

makes them static.
Look at the compiled JS while developing on CoffeeScript.

Comment: This plus using the `new` keyword and you should be set. `f = new Foo()`

Comment: And rewriting the `if a == 1` to `if Foo::a == 1` since `a` is also in the prototype.

Comment: sorry I omitted the `new` keyword by it is in the original source. This seems to have worked. Thanks.